# What was regicide conspiracy and what was the role of Djordje Gencic in it?

Tags: world-war-one, serbia

I'm reading the book [The Sleepwalkers by Christopher Clarke](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061146668), and it says that the interior minister during the rule of Alexander in Serbia (late 1890s), was involved in [regicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regicide) conspiracy. However I checked the reference and couldn't find the book "[Apis" by "David MacKenzie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0880331623)" in nearby library. Could somebody shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found then answer later in the book, the regicide conspiracy was to assassinate then king Alexander of Serbia.

Comment: ...that's what "regicide" usually implies, yes...?!?

Comment: Yeah I thought it was not a word, later realized my mistake